# Running "Get-Service | Stop-Service" command in Powershell

Tags: powershell

What would happen if `Get-Service | Stop-Service` was executed in Powershell without any other commands? Would this actually cause damage? I know you can run this with the `-whatif` flag to see the description of what would happen, but would it cause issues if actually ran?

I'm a  bit new to Powershell, if this isn't already obvious.

Comment: It would stop all services you have permission to stop. This isn't going to cause "damage" in the sense of physically damaging the hardware, but it will cause some OS features to stop functioning. It's probable you might need a reboot to get everything up to scratch again (not merely starting all the services again).  Feel free to actually try it -- on a VM. There is no *practical* use for it, though.

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario is exactly what -whatif was designed for.  Your code will get all services on the system and pipe a ServiceController object to Stop-Service which will attempt to stop the Service.

Assuming you have the permissions you'll stop every service on the system.  Your system will mostly likely crash, at best the system will be in an unresponsive state.

When I started teaching PowerShell 12 years ago I use Get-Service | Stop-Service as an example - usually asking who would be willing to run it on their most critical server. I never did get many takers. I'd then go on to show -whatif.

get-process | stop-process is another combination that has the capability of crashing your system